# How can I get from Miami airport to the hotel if I don't have a car seat for my baby?

Tags: child-safety-seats, miami

I am flying to Miami from South America this month with my family (my wife and my baby of 5 months) and made a reservation of a Minivan (Hertz). My intention is to buy a child seat (USD 150) on Amazon and send it to the Hotel (in Sunny Isles).

My idea was to rent the child seat 1 day with Hertz, so I can return it the next day, but they only offer the whole period rent (10 days; USD 90).

Is there a different solution I am not seeing?

Comment: Let me get this straight - you're trying to decide between $90 and $150, and the $150 option is your preferred choice?

Comment: Are you renting the car for the whole stay or just to get to the hotel ? Can't you just take a taxi (reserve it with a baby seat) to your hotel ?

Comment: @GregHewgill my preferred choice is $150 option, because after that I can bring the child seat to my home.

Comment: @Max I'm renting the car for the whole stay. The problem is the rental doesn't allow the one day rent for the seat. This is what they said to me.

Comment: You could just take the risk make that short drive without a child seat.

Comment: A problem with taking the risk is that this may be the most dangerous journey: tired after the flight and an unfamiliar car in an unfamiliar country.

Answer (score 6):

Since you have two adults, one of you could drive the rental car from the airport to the hotel, and the other could go with your baby in a taxi or shuttle (or some service that provides a child seat).

Comment: Ok, this is an option... do you know what could be the price for that distance? What type of service? Like Uber?

Comment: One option would be to take transit for $2.25 https://goo.gl/maps/v3MVJ9qaxnJ2. You don't need a car seat for a child in this case since buses are extremely safe (see http://usa.streetsblog.org/2014/12/19/heres-how-much-safer-transit-is-compared-to-driving/).

Comment: @CarlfromBusbud thanks for your response. This also could be a good solution for me.

Answer (score 6):

Perhaps a solution would be to have you (or your husband) rent the car, drive to the [Mall of the Americas](http://malloftheamericas.com), as there are stores there that sell baby related products such as a car seat, then come back to the airport and pick you guys up.

The Mall is [across the highway](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Mall+of+the+Americas/@25.7911363,-80.3100324,14.25z/data=!4m12!1m6!3m5!1s0x88d9b74d4eb94ac1:0x989fdae0cba2f8e1!2sMiami+International+Airport+(MIA)!8m2!3d25.795865!4d-80.2870457!3m4!1s0x0:0x4de0facdbf3c103d!8m2!3d25.7740592!4d-80.3227401) from Miami International Airport.

Or why not buy the car seat while you are in South America, then bring it to the US to use? Generally international flights include checked luggage, and since you are already planning on bringing it from the US back to South America, I don't see why it's a bad idea to bring it round-trip. If you purchase one that is can be used on the plane as well as a car, that might be even better.

Answer (score 5):

(fine, this particular trip is long finished.....)

Lets review the key points:

- You are renting the car for 10 days, but only want a child seat for one day. Hertz doesn't do that.
- You are renting the car at an airport.

Make two reservations:

1. At the airport for one day, with child seat, returning to a non-airport location.
2. At the same non-airport location, without child seat, for the rest of your trip, returning to the airport.

You get two benefits here:

- The car seat is only for the time you want, not the whole rental
- The airport location charge only applies to the one day, not the entire rental. At $110 a day for a minivan and 15% for the airport, this fully pays for the car seat.